# Finding property value by string getting

Tags: typescript

Hey I am having an issue looking up strings in a class based on class properties in typescript.

```
export class EventName {
   public static LOGIN = "LOGIN";
   public static LOGOUT = "LOGOUT";
}
```

I looked online and it says to just use something like eventName['LOGIN'];

However this returns the following error

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof EventName' has no index signature.

I then tried adding in
    [key: string]: any;
But this still gives me the same error. I was wondering could someone please point me to the issue here thanks?

Comment: I can't replicate this in the TypeScript Playground - could you show exactly what code is giving you the error, and specify which version of TypeScript you're using? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20EventName%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20static%20LOGIN%20%3D%20%22LOGIN%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20static%20LOGOUT%20%3D%20%22LOGOUT%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%20%3D%20EventName%5B'LOGIN'%5D%3B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt your example `eventName['LOGIN'];` using an *instance* of the `EventName` class, you'll get that error (if you are using `--noImplicitAny`):

```
class EventName {
   public static LOGIN = "LOGIN";
   public static LOGOUT = "LOGOUT";
}

const eventName = new EventName();

// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'EventName' has no index signature.
const logout = eventName['LOGOUT'];
```

This is because the properties are `static` and don't belong to an instance - so you can use:

```
class EventName {
   public static LOGIN = "LOGIN";
   public static LOGOUT = "LOGOUT";
}

// login: string;
const login = EventName['LOGIN'];
```

This might be a good example of why the `--noImplicitAny` flag is terribly useful.